# Show time with seconds

Tags: nexus-4, clock

How can I see the time with seconds on a Nexus 4? The settings give me the option to only change the date format, but not the time format.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Do you want time with seconds in the clock app? In the status bar? On your lockscreen? Somewhere else?

Comment: @dotVezz Anywhere possible. I looked in all those places and couldn't find a way to show seconds. So, I'm looking to be able to just see the seconds.

Comment: Changing to Analog will show seconds hand, that's the only way I could find.

Comment: @dotVezz In the status bar how do I display hh:mm:ss?

Answer (score 2):

Try any of these:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=smsr.com.acc
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.topaz.psy.androidapp.SecondStatus
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gridred.digitalclock.custom.lite&hl=en

This one claims to show the time including seconds in the Status Bar
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsynapse.bottime&hl=en

Be advised that displaying seconds will consume more battery.

Comment: Besides installing a new app, what other options do I have?

Comment: Well if you are comfortable with programming..give this a go.  
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2058151

Comment: this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsynapse.bottime&hl=en link is not active anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

Try a [Terminal Emulator app](https://play.google.com/store/search?c=apps&q=terminal%20emulator):

> $ **date**
>
> Fri Mar 27 16:00:15 IDT 2015

Comment: Not really what I was asking for, but a good idea.